# What is the full syntax SQL reference for the `geometry` data type?

Tags: postgis

I have a database in which a field has the data type `geometry(Geometry, 4326)`. In another similar database a field merely had the data type `geometry`.

Where can I find the full reference on this data type? Where can I find the list of possible values for the first argument to `geometry()`? I couldn't find them in the PostGIS manual.

Answer (score 3):

Document in https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#RefObject says

> The GIS objects supported by PostGIS are a superset of the "Simple
>   Features" defined by the OpenGIS Consortium (OGC). PostGIS supports
>   all the objects and functions specified in the OGC "Simple Features
>   for SQL" specification. PostGIS extends the standard with support for
>   3DZ, 3DM and 4D coordinates.

The Simple Features standard is this http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25354.

The geometry types can found from Table 4: Geometry type codes

```
0 GEOMETRY \\ IN X Y
1 POINT \\ IN X Y
2 LINESTRING \\ IN X Y
3 POLYGON \\ IN X Y
4 MULTIPOINT \\ IN X Y
5 MULTILINESTRING \\ IN X Y
6 MULTIPOLYGON \\ IN X Y
7 GEOMCOLLECTION \\ IN X Y
13 CURVE \\ IN X Y
14 SURFACE \\ IN X Y
15 POLYHEDRALSURFACE \\ IN X Y
1000 GEOMETRYZ \\ IN X Y Z
1001 POINTZ \\ IN X Y Z
1002 LINESTRINGZ \\ IN X Y Z
1003 POLYGONZ \\ IN X Y Z
1004 MULTIPOINTZ \\ IN X Y Z
1005 MULTILINESTRINGZ \\ IN X Y Z
1006 MULTIPOLYGONZ \\ IN X Y Z
1007 GEOMCOLLECTIONZ \\ IN X Y Z
1013 CURVEZ \\ IN X Y M
1014 SURFACEZ \\ IN X Y M
1015 POLYHEDRALSURFACEZ \\ IN X Y Z
2000 GEOMETRY \\ IN X Y M
2001 POINTM \\ IN X Y M
2002 LINESTRINGM \\ IN X Y M
2003 POLYGONM \\ IN X Y M
2004 MULTIPOINTM \\ IN X Y M
2005 MULTILINESTRINGM \\ IN X Y M
2006 MULTIPOLYGONM \\ IN X Y M
2007 GEOMCOLLECTIONM \\ IN X Y M
2013 CURVEM \\ IN X Y M
2014 SURFACEM \\ IN X Y M
2015 POLYHEDRALSURFACEM \\ IN X Y M
3000 GEOMETRYZM \\ IN X Y Z M
3001 POINTZM \\ IN X Y Z M
3002 LINESTRINGZM \\ IN X Y Z M
3003 POLYGONZM \\ IN X Y Z M
3004 MULTIPOINTZM \\ IN X Y Z M
3005 MULTILINESTRINGZM \\ IN X Y Z M
3006 MultiPolygonZM \\ IN X Y Z M
3007 GEOMCOLLECTIONZM \\ IN X Y Z M
3013 CURVEZM \\ IN X Y Z M
3014 SURFACEZM \\ IN X Y Z M
3015 POLYHEDRALSURFACEZM \\ IN X Y Z M
```

PostGIS supports also a general "Geometry" that means any of the above.

Answer (score 3):

In this [document](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geometries.html) you will have a good look of the possibilities. To resume the main idea, the `geometry` type means every kind of geometry is accepted, `geometry(geometry, 4326)` means only geometries with the SRID 4326 are accepted. Others type can be seen like just constraints on the field.

For exemple there is `POINT`,`LINESTRING`,`POLYGON` or geometry collections (basically a group of geometry) like `MULTIPOINT`,`MULTILINESTRING`,`MULTIPOLYGON` or the generic collection `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`.

You also have the specific type `GEOGRAPHY` (instead of GEOMETRY field, not as a type of geometry) for not projected data, a lot of functions now can handle these type of data with geodesic calculation, or just handle local UTM projection themself wich is quite convenient.